# Detect if jQuery is running

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to run an animation everytime any jQuery function is running (eg.: animations, fadeIn(), fadeOut()..etc.). How can I detect if a jQuery function is started, so I can run the animation?

Comment: Seems an odd request, what is the practical use of this other than to slow stuff down a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to achieve this by extending `jQuery` with your own (wrapper) function e.g `.myAnimate()`:

```
$.fn.myAnimate = function(properties, duration, easing, complete){
   alert('detect');
   $(this).animate(properties, duration, easing, complete);
}
```

or

```
$.fn.myAnimate = function(options, callback){
   alert('detect');
   $(this).animate(options, callback);
}
```

Then animate your elements like so:

```
$('#mydiv').myAnimate(...)
```

Amend it to fit your needs. A working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5mAC/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful. But can you help me with a few more code lines? Look at this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/CHMmB/) 

What should be added in the code to disappear that loading animation, when that div finished animating. I know only to show it when it start.

Comment: There you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtrMh/).. basically added the anonymous callback function the usual way.. let me know if it did the trick